# Projection and positive elements in unital C*-algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

If $a$ is a positive element in a unital C*-algebra $\mathcal{A}$, with norm $\|a\|=1$. Let $P$ be a non-zero positive projection in $\mathcal{A}$. How to prove:
$$P\leq a \Longleftrightarrow aP=P ?$$
Also, if for any pure state $f$ such that $f(P)=1$, we always have $f(a)=1$, then it implies $P\leq a$.

I'm thinking of the hereditary C*-subalgebra, the closure of $a\mathcal{A}a$. But can't see how to proceed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $ap=p$, taking adjoints you get $pa=p$. Then $ap=pa$ and
$$
p=a^{1/2}pa^{1/2}\leq a^{1/2}1a^{1/2}=a.
$$
Conversely, if $p\leq a$ then $1-a\leq 1-p$. So
$$
0\leq p(1-a)p\leq p(1-p)p=0.
$$
Thus $p(1-a)p=0$. We can write this as $[(1-a)^{1/2}p]^*(1-a)^{1/2}p=0$, and so $(1-a)^{1/2}p=0$, from where we get $(1-a)p=0$. That is $ap=p$.

As for your other question, suppose that $f(a)=1$ whenever $f$ is a pure state with $f(p)=1$. For such a state we have by Cauchy-Schwarz
$$\tag1
|f(a(1-p))|≤f(aa^*)^{1/2}\,f(1-p)^{1/2}=0.
$$
Therefore $f(a(1-p))=0$. Then $1=f(p)=f(ap)=f(pa)$.

Let $g$ be a pure state of the subalgebra $pAp$. We can extend $g$ to a state of $A$ by $\tilde g(x)=g(pxp)$. Suppose that $\tilde g=th+(1-t)k$ for states $h,k$ and $t\in[0,1]$. Since $th\leq\tilde g$ and $\tilde g(1-p)=0$, we get that $h(1-p)=0$. Using Cauchy-Schwarz as above we get $h((1-p)x)=0$ for all $x$. It follows that $h(x)=h(pxp)$ for all $x$ and similarly for $k$. Then $h,k$ can be seen as states on $pAp$ and by the purity of $g$ we get that $h=k=g $. So $\tilde g$ is pure.

As we just showed, any pure state $f$ of $pAp$ can be seen as a pure state of $A$ with $f(p)=1$. Then $f(a)=1$; we have from $(1)$ (note that the positivity of $a$ was not used there) that
$$
f(a(1-p))=f((1-p)ap)=0.
$$
Then
$$
1=f(a)=f(ap+a(1-p))=f(ap)=f(pap).
$$ This can be done for any pure state of $pAp$ and pure states separate points, so we have $pap=p$. This we can write as $p(1-a)p=0$. As we showed before, this gives us $ap=p$ and thus $p\leq a$.

Comment: May I ask how to get $p=a^{\frac{1}{2}}p a^{\frac{1}{2}}$? Is it because $p=\left(p^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)^2$, and $p^{\frac{1}{2}}=a^{\frac{1}{2}}p^{\frac{1}{2}}=p^{\frac{1}{2}}a^{\frac{1}{2}}$?

Comment: Also, why is $0\leq p(1-a)p$? Is it because, $0\leq 1-a$, since $\sigma(1-a)=1-\sigma(a)\subset [0,1]$, since $\sigma(a)\subset [0,1]$?

Comment: Once you know that $ap=pa$, it is easy to get that $a^{1/2}p=pa^{1/2}$. Then $$p=ap=a^{1/2}a^{1/2}p=a^{1/2}pa^{1/2}.$$ For your second question, $a\geq0$ and $\|a\|≤1$ is equivalent with $0\leq a\leq 1$, as you say; and conjugating by an element and it's adjoint preserves order ($0\leq b$ $\implies$ $0\leq cbc^*$).

Comment: In the Cauchy-Swcharz, $$|f(a(1-p))|≤f(a^*a)^{1/2}\,f(1-p)=0,$$ may I ask why there isn't the square root for $f(1-p)$? Also, $a$ positive, so $a^* a=a^2$? Also, is there a typo in $f(a(1-p))=f(a(1-p))=0$? And where does the last part in $1=f(p)=f(ap)=f(pa)$ come from?

Comment: Also, can you elaborate on "using Cauchy-Schwarz as before we get that $f(p-pap)=0$? I can't seem to get it work. It seems we have
$$\left|f(p(1-ap))\right|^2\leq \left|f(p)\right|\left|f((1-pa)(1-ap)\right|$$
But don't see how to get $0$.

Comment: I have corrected the typos and edited a few more details in. It is true that $a^*a=a^2$ when $a$ is positive, but that argument doesn't require the positivity of $a$, so using it feels kind of wasteful.

Comment: Does the $f(ap)=f(pa)$ part come from using the same steps for $|f((1-p)a)|\leq 0$?

Comment: If you know that $f(ap)=1$, you have $$f(pa)=f((ap)^*)=\overline{f(ap)}=\overline1=1. $$ This uses that both $a,p$ are positive.

Comment: Sorry still don't see how $$f(a(1-p))=f((1-p)ap)=0.$$ Where does $(1-p)ap$ come from?

Comment: $$0\leq|f((1-p)ap)|\leq f(1-p)^{1/2} f((ap)^*ap)=0. $$

Comment: Oh so it's for getting to the next line. I see. Btw, can't we directly say a pure state on $pAp$ extents to a pure state on $A$? Lat time with Quantum's answer, they directly used that. Is it not true here because $1_A$ isn't in $pAp$?

Comment: You can use Murphy's Theorem instead, yes. But in the case of $pAp$, there is no theory needed and the extension is explicit.