# Projections and positive elements in unital von Neumann algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

A follow up for [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4545340/416552) question. If $\mathcal{A}$ is a unital von Neumann algebra and $a\in\mathcal{A}$ is a positive element such that $\|a\|=1$. Let $p \in\mathcal{A}$ be a non-zero projection. When does the following statement fail? Is there a counter-example?

$p\leq a$ iff, for every nozero projection $\mathcal{A}\ni q\leq p$, we have $\|a- (1-q)\|=1$.

Also, is there a short proof for when it's true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\implies)$ since from $p\leq a$ we know that $p=ap$. Then $ap=pa$ and $$ a=ap+a(1-p)=p+a(1-p).$$ If $q\leq p$ then $1-q=(p-q)+1-p$ and then
$$
a-(1-q)=q+(a-1)(1-p). 
$$
Then
$$
\|a-(1-q)\|=\max\{\|q\|,\|(a-1)(1-p)\|\}=\|q\|=1, 
$$
since $\|(a-1)(1-p)\|\leq\|a-1\|\,\|1-p\|\leq1$.

$\impliedby)$ This only works when $a$ is injective (see at the botoom for a counterexample when $a$ is not injective). Let $q\leq p$. Then $\|a-(1-q)\|=1$. Assume that $a$ is injective. Since $a-(1-q)$ is selfadjoint, its norm is achieved on the numerical range. That is, there exists $x$ with $\|x \|=1$ such that
$$\tag1
\langle (a+q-1)x,x\rangle=\pm1.
$$
When equal to $-1$, $(1)$ becomes
$$
\langle ax,x \rangle+\langle qx,x \rangle=0.
$$
This would imply that $ax=0$, contradicting that $a$ is injective. So we have
$$
\langle ax,x \rangle+\langle qx,x \rangle=2.
$$
As both summands are at most $1$, it follows that
$$
\langle ax,x \rangle=1,\qquad\qquad \langle qx,x \rangle=1.
$$
The last equality reads $\|qx\|=1$, and we deduce that $qx=x $. This allows us to write $\langle qaqx,x\rangle=1$, and we conclude that $$\tag2\|qaq\|=1,\qquad\qquad q\leq p.$$
Now fix $\alpha\in(0,1)$. Take $q=1_{[0,\alpha]}(pap)$. Then $q\leq p$, and
$$
qaq=aq \leq\alpha q.
$$
Then $qaq=0$, as otherwise we would have $\|qaq \|\leq\alpha<1$, a contradiction. This shows that $pap=1_{\{1\}}(pap)$, implying that $pap$ is a projection. We have
$$
pa^2p\leq pap=(pap)^2=papap\leq pa^2p.
$$
Thus $pa^2p=papap$, which we can write as $pa(1-p)ap=0$. This in turn implies $(1-p)ap=0$, so $ap=pap$ and $ap=pa$. In particular $ap=pap\leq p$. If $q=p-ap\ne 0$, we get $q\leq p$ and
$$
qaq=q (ap)q=(p-ap)ap(p-ap)=0,
$$
contradicting $(2)$. So $ap=p$, and hence $p\leq a$.

---

When $a$ is not injective, the reverse implication can fail. For example let $M=M_3(\mathbb C)$, and
$$
a=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix},
\qquad\qquad
p=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}
$$
Any $q\leq p$ is of the form
$$
q=\begin{bmatrix} t&\sqrt{t-t^2}&0\\\sqrt{t-t^2}&1-t&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then
$$
a-(1-q)=\begin{bmatrix} t&\sqrt{t-t^2}&0\\\sqrt{t-t^2}&-t&0\\0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}
$$
and hence
$$
\|a\|=1,\qquad\qquad p\not\leq a,\qquad \qquad \|a-(1-q)\|=1\ \ \ \forall q\leq p. 
$$
This situation can be achieved for most projections $p$ in most von Neumann algebras. Namely, given a non-trivial, non-minimal projection $p$, let $q_0\leq p$ be a proper subprojection, and put $a=q_0$. Then $p\not\leq a$ and for any $q_1\leq p$ we have
$$
a-(1-q_1)=q_0+q_1-1.
$$
For any $x$ with $(1-p)x=x$, we have $(a-(1-q_1)x=-x$, and so $\|a-(1-q_1)\|=1$.

Comment: Don't we have $$\|a-(1-q)\|=\|a-(1-p)\|=1/\sqrt{2}?$$

Comment: For $x^2+y^2=1$, 

$$\begin{pmatrix}1/2 & 1/2 \\ 1/2 & -1/2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x\\y\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} (x+y)/2 \\ (x-y)/2\end{pmatrix}.$$

But $$\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)^2 +\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)^2=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: Yes, the norm is wrong. My bad. I'll try to look at it later today.

Comment: Can you prove the statement when $\mathcal{A}$ is type I finite?

Comment: I included an argument. It is not complete (there is one case that the argument doesn't cover), but I have to leave it for now.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try to digest it for now

Comment: May I ask what $\wedge$ is in the above answer? I can't seem to find its definition in Murphy (1990). Is it related to the tensor product?

Comment: It's the intersection of the projections; $p\wedge q$ is the projection onto the intersection of the ranges of $p$ and $q$. Murphy is a great book to learn C$^*$-algebras, but it is not a von Neumann algebra book and it doesn't pretend to be one. The stuff on von Neumann algebras is very limited, mostly to basic results he needs foro the C$^*$-algebra theory.

Comment: It seems von Neumann algebras are always constructed concretely on $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$, but for C*-algebras it's always abstractly defined then use GNS representations to identity them with operators. Can you recommend an authoritative book on von Neumann algebras please?

Comment: Because abstract C$^*$-algebras exist naturally, while abstract von Neumann algebras  mostly don't. As for books, a canonical textbook is Kadison-Ringrose (particularly chapters 6 and 7, and maybe 8, in the second volume). Sunder's *An Invitation to von Neumann Algebras* has a strong focus on Tomita-Takesaki theory, that you probably don't need, but it has the basic stuff expressed in a simplified way (partily because he works mostly on factors instead of arbitrary algebras). There are others, too, of course, but I'm less familiar with the virtues/defects.

Comment: I came back to think about it, and it turns out that the reverse implication can fail when $a$ is not injective.

Comment: So it has nothing to do with Type I or other types?

Comment: No. $ \ \ \ \ $

Comment: May I ask why do we have $(a-(1-q_1))x=-x$?

Comment: $$ (q_0+q_1-1)x=(q_0+q_1)x-x=(q_0+q_1)(1-p)x-x=(q_0p+q_1p)(1-p)x-x=-x. $$